# ObjectAnimator duration not respected

Tags: android, animation, scroll, scrollview, objectanimator

I'm trying to create an animation in order to scroll automatically in my scrollview.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) scrollView.getChildAt(0);
// linearLayout.getHeight() == 540
animScroll = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scrollView, "scrollY", linearLayout.getHeight());

// animationDurationLong == 154000
animScroll.setDuration(animationDurationLong);
animScroll.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());

animScroll.start();
```

My animation is working perfectly, I scroll from the top of my scrollview content to the bottom BUT I do it in 96 seconds, instead of the 154 seconds set in duration.

Does anyone know why ? I check developer settings of my phone, tried on two devices, still the same problem.

Comment: the last param of `ofInt` is wrong, you need: `content height - container height`

Comment: You are right, Thanks pskink. Can you post the answer so I valide your answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your target `"scrollY"` is probably wrong (the last param of `ofInt`), you need something like this:

```
height_of_content - height_of_container
```

Comment: Thanks pskink, in my example I did : animScroll = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(scrollView, "scrollY", linearLayout.getHeight() - scrollView.getHeight()); It works now !

Comment: so now the animation doesn't end too early... of course be prepared if it is < 0 ;-)